# PyQt QtCharts Designer plugin

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have tried the procedure ([Qt Charts and Data Visualization widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869807/qt-charts-and-data-visualization-widgets)) to integrate the qtchart plugin. 
But it don't work. Makeing the plugin and add it to the desinger folder worked. qt designer ‎recognize the plugin but compiling the ui to a python file I get following error:

Unknown Qt widget: QtCharts.QChartView

I'm using linux with qt 5.7 and qtcharts and also pyqtcharts.

I thing the problem is the 's' at the end of QtCharts, but I have no idea how I can fix it.

Hope someone has a idea.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to integrate it.
Add a normal `Widget` in qt-designer, then right click it, and select `Promote to ...`.

In the window that opens, write `QChartView` for the `Promoted class name:`, and `PyQt5.QtChart` for the `Header file:`. Press `Add`. It will be added to the list of Promoted Classes. Select it from the list, and press `Promote`. That's it.

Then in your python code, you can write something like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtChart   import QChart, QLineSeries
...
chart = QChart()
series = QLineSeries()

series.append(1,3)
series.append(2,4)

chart.addSeries(series)
chart.setTitle('Example')
chart.createDefaultAxes()

self.ui.widget.setChart(chart) # this is the view you added in qt-designer
```

Make sure you have `pyqtchart` installed (with pip).